# How to save all figures in pdf file in python created from seaborn style & dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, seaborn

This code gives me output of grid as [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip4ib.jpg) with style background.

```
def plot(grid):
    cmap = sns.light_palette("red", as_cmap=True)
    figure = pd.DataFrame(grid)
    figure = figure.style.background_gradient(cmap=cmap, axis=None)
    display(figure)
```

I wanted to store multiples images such as [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip4ib.jpg) in a single pdf file generated by Fun 'plot'.In case of matplotlib

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfFile,PdfPages
pdfFile = PdfPages("name.pdf")
pdfFile.savefig(plot)
pdfFile.close()
```

can do this. but for this case I am facing issues because it is dataframe or I am using searborn background_style.
could you please suggest to store output of above in single pdf file or png or jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code to save all open figures to a pdf, it saves each plot to a separate page in the pdf.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

pp = PdfPages('C:\path\filename.pdf') #path to where you want to save the pdf
figNum = plt.get_fignums() #creates a list of all figure numbers

for i in range(len(figNum)): #loop to add each figure to pdf
    pp.savefig(figNum[i]) #uses the figure number in the list to save it to the pdf
pp.close() #closes the opened file in memory
```

Answer (score 0):

We can creat folder name 'image' and store all images of code output in png format.we will have to use dataframe image for that.

```
import dataframe_image as dfi
from PIL import Image

 def plot(grid):
        cmap = sns.light_palette("red", as_cmap=True)
        figure = pd.DataFrame(grid)
        figure = figure.style.background_gradient(cmap=cmap, axis=None)
        dfi.export(figure, f'image\df_styled.png, max_cols=-1)
```